# How to get unique values in Python using list/dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I need to get only unique values from the field "city" in my dictionary. I need to do it using list/dict comprehension.

```
people = [ dict ( city = "Liverpool" , name = "Adam" , age = 24 ),
{ "city" : "New York" , "name" : "Dario" , "age" : 12 },
{ "city" : "New York" , "name" : "Mario" , "age" : 45 },
{ "city" : "Chicago" , "name" : "Paolo" , "age" : 27 },
{ "city" : "Brighton" , "name" : "Sven" , "age" : 19 },
{ "city" : "Berlin" , "name" : "Frank" , "age" : 52 },
{ "city" : "Rome" , "name" : "Aleksander" , "age" : 33 }
{ "city" : "Rome" , "name" : "Adam," , "age" : 24 }]
```

I've done it with loop this way:

```
unique_cities = []
for x in range(len(people)):
    y = people[x]
    cities = y.get('city')
    unique_cities.append(cities)
unique_cities = list(dict.fromkeys(unique_cities))
print(unique_cities)
```

But I haven't dealt with list/dict comprehension before. I can only print all values like this:

```
for x in range(len(people)):
    y = people[x]
    dict_comp = {k:v for (k, v) in y.items()}
    print(dict_comp)
```

Comment: `print( list(set(i["city"] for i in people)) )`

Answer (score 4):

List comprehension, and pass it to a set.

```
set(person['city'] for person in people)
```

note: actually, this is a *generator expression*, not a list comprehension, but in this case they are equivalent for most purposes

Comment: Why do a list comprehension and then convert it to a set when you can directly do a set comprehension?

Comment: @glhr: correct. Actually, what I have written is not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Entries in a set are unique by definition, so a set comprehension is exactly what you need here:

```
{d["city"] for d in people}
```

Output:

```
{'Berlin', 'Rome', 'Brighton', 'Liverpool', 'Chicago', 'New York'}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your list contains two syntaxes for dictionary definition: `dict + keywords` and `key: value` inside accolades. That's not a problem, but that's weird.

Second, in Python you usually don't need the index of the loop:

```
for x in range(len(people)):
    y = people[x]
    ...
```

Is the same as:

```
for y in people:
    ...
```

If you need the index, you have the `enumerate` keyword:

```
for x, y in enumerate(people):
    ...
```

Third:

```
    dict_comp = {k:v for (k, v) in y.items()}
```

makes a (shallow) copy of `y` and assigns it to `dict_comp`. That's not required in your case:

```
for y in people:
    print(y)
```

Fourth, `dict.fromkeys` is the poor man's `set`. Both solutions are roughly equivalent, but `set` looses the order of insertion (tested in 3.6) whereas `dict.fromkeys` keeps the order insertion of a key (>= 3.6):

```
>>> set(person['city'] for person in people)
{'Rome', 'Chicago', 'New York', 'Brighton', 'Liverpool', 'Berlin'}
>>> dict.fromkeys(person['city'] for person in people)
{'Liverpool': None, 'New York': None, 'Chicago': None, 'Brighton': None, 'Berlin': None, 'Rome': None}
```

If you want the order of the first apparition of a key, you can also write:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [person['city'] for person in people if not (person['city'] in seen or seen.add(person['city']))]
['Liverpool', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Brighton', 'Berlin', 'Rome']
```

Every time a new `city` is met, the list comprehension adds it to the output and to the `seen` `set` (beware: side effect inside the list comprehension):

```
>>> seen
{'Berlin', 'Liverpool', 'Rome', 'New York', 'Brighton', 'Chicago'}
```